# chrome.sockets.tcp.secure and TLS handshaking not working as expected

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, google-chrome-app

I am doing a Chrome Application using the new Socket API (Chrome.sockets.tcp). I have been able to successfully get all HTTP requests working without any issue. The problem that I have run into is the HTTPS login with TLS handshake. We created a Visual Studio C# (RestRequest) application. We are able to connect using HTTPS. Using Wireshark, I notice that the successful communication was achieved using the TLSv1.

I have tried a variety of solutions and referenced/experimented with the below links and tried to come up with a solution.

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/net-dev/U2ecAARKvAg/WI1WrSlaOPMJ
- [SSL Client Authentication with Certificate in Chrome App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911137/ssl-client-authentication-with-certificate-in-chrome-app)

Plus many more links! I have written a pile of test applications, but all reach a dead end after the initial handshake.

The following code sequence seems to get the handshake done, but I cannot send the login post. It seems as though the socket is messed up after the handshake. (WireShark shows all com’s were successful up until the login post).

```js
var that = this;
chrome.sockets.tcp.create({
     persistent: false,
     name: "hc",
     bufferSize: 8192
}, function (createInfo) {
     console.log("create info = " + JSON.stringify(createInfo));
     if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
         error('Unable to create socket: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
     }
     that._socketId = createInfo.socketId;
     chrome.sockets.tcp.setPaused(that._socketId, true, function () {
         chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(that._socketId, that._httpHost, that._httpPort, function (result) {
             chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(that._onReceive.bind(this));
             chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError.addListener(that._onReceiveError.bind(this));
             chrome.sockets.tcp.secure(that._socketId, function (secureResult) {
                 chrome.sockets.tcp.send(that._socketId, str2ab('POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: ' + that._httpHost + '\r\n\r\n'), function (sendResult) {});
             });
         });
     });
});
```

I have tried implementing the TLSSocket from nmp forge and I get the same result as the example above.

We have to use TCP for this application, mainly for cookie support in a Chrome App.

Does anybody have a solution or suggestion? We have put in a lot of hours with trial and error, and seems like we have hit a dead end.

Comment: What is purpose of using `.bind()`?

Comment: You have multiple things in your code that are defined outside your code. Please include a complete [mcve] in your question.

Comment: This question is very similar to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42520631/3773011) from two days ago. If you don't want this one closed as a duplicate of that one, please [edit] the question to include and explanation as to the difference between the two. Normally you should have edited the older question to better describe the problem, not posted a new one (assuming they are about the same problem, which is what it looks like to me).

Comment: BTW: Chrome Apps are not Chrome extensions. I have removed the [tag:chrome-extensions] tag, again. They have different available APIs.

Comment: bind is a callback in a class

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpause the socket after it's secured.  e.g. `chrome.sockets.tcp.setPaused(that._socketId, false, ...)`